# WPF, using XPath in XAML with XmlDataProvider to select nodes based on selected value in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, xpath

This question ties to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388759/wpf-xml-databinding-into-dependent-cascading-comboboxes) but is more specific.  Say I have two ComboBoxes, one populated with product names, the other empty.  When a product is chosen, I want the second ComboBox to be filled with data related to that product.  I have XML like the following:

```
<Products>
    <Product name="MyProduct1">
        <Components>
            <Component name="MyComponent1"/>
            <Component name="MyComponent2"/>
            ...more Component nodes...
        </Components>
    </Product>
    ...more Product nodes...
</Products>
```

What I was hoping is that I could somehow set the `XPath` on the Component ComboBox such that it gets all the `Components/Component` nodes from the `Product` node whose `@name` attribute is equal to the currently selected value in the Product ComboBox.  Is this possible?  How would I do it?  Here's what I have in my XAML so far:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,116,0,0"
          Name="cbo_product" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource productsXml}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="@name"/>
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,151,0,0"
            Name="cbo_component" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201"
            DisplayMemberPath="@name">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <!-- Currently gets all Component nodes--want it to get only those
             associated with the selected Product -->
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource productsXml}"
                 XPath="Components/Component"/>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

The Product ComboBox is filled with product names like MyProduct1, so that part is fine.  It's the dependent Component ComboBox I need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Googling around for examples of XPath expressions in WPF, I found [this article](http://karlhulme.wordpress.com/2007/02/14/xpath-variabledynamic-parameters-in-wpf-binding/) that gave me my solution in a round-about way.  His example was more complicated than mine, so I didn't have to go creating XML converter classes.  I just needed the following XAML for my dependent Component ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,151,0,0"
          Name="cbo_component" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201"
          DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbo_product, Path=SelectedItem}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Components/Component}"
          DisplayMemberPath="@name"/>
```

Here, `cbo_product` is the `Name` of my Product ComboBox.