# Two connected comboboxes + XML + DataBinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xmldataprovider

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388759/wpf-xml-databinding-into-dependent-cascading-comboboxes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389333/wpf-using-xpath-in-xaml-with-xmldataprovider-to-select-nodes-based-on-selected).
Here is a description:

I have a following XML:

```
<Parts>
  <Part id="1" name="part1">
    <SubParts>
      <SubPart id="1" name="sub_part1"/>
      <SubPart id="2" name="sub_part2"/>
    </SubParts>
  </Part>
  ...
</Parts>
```

Sure, I want to have two dependent `ComboBox` items in my WPF control - one for parts and one for subparts.

The difference from the solution above is that I **don't want to replace the DataContext of the second `ComboBox`** because than I loose the parent DataContext binding.

I want to get something like this:

```
  <ComboBox x:Name="_partCombo"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlPartList}, XPath=./Part}"
              ...
              SelectedValue="{Binding PartID}"/>

  <ComboBox x:Name="_subPartCombo"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlPartList}, XPath=./Part/SubParts}"
              ...
              SelectedValue="{Binding SubPartID}"/>
```

I tried using intermediate data member to bind the selected item from first `ComboBox` but I cannot bind to it from the second one.

Any help required.

Comment: It appears that you have duplicate x:Name and than should be then.  You might try binding the second CompboBox to the Element main ComboBox with a Path of SelecteItem.SubPartID.

Comment: Updated combobox name. Could you provide a piece of code? I understand  the idea but cannot write it.

Comment: Search on binding to an element.  If it is an XML parsing problem then it is going to be hard to debug.

Comment: Are you using WPF or SL?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlPartList}, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},
                      XPath=./Part/SubParts}"
```

Comment: What you gave looks like a SL syntax. In WPF is'll be: AncestorType={x:Type Window}}