# Xml Binding ComboBox different SelectedValue and Itemssource DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have read many posts on this subject but I can't wrap my head around it. I have a `ComboBox` of which the `ItemSource` is binded to an `XmlDataProvider`. It looks like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=List/ListItem}">
```

I need the `SelectedValue` to be binded to an `XPath` property of a selected item of a `ListBox`. So I have two different datacontexts. The `ListBox` is binded to the same `XmlDataProvider`. I tried this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=List/ListItems}" SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName="MyListBox" Path=SelectedItem.MyXPathProperty}">
```

But it didn't work. In the other posts people referenced to a normal property but I need to reference to an `XPath` property.

How can I bind the `SelectedValue` to an `XPath` property of a different element?

```
<ListItems>
<MyNode MyXPathProperty="SomeValue">
<MyNode MyXPathProperty="SomeValue">
<MyNode MyXPathProperty="SomeValue">
</ListItems>
```

Comment: Might help if you included a demo xml that you are binding to (easier to get help when people have all the pieces) , so who ever is looking at the problem can copy paste and try things out to give you an answer.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3389985/4632606) helps me to resolve the same issue.